# Passing/Keeping/Returning String From Form/Dialog - C++ /CLI

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

I am trying to pass a reference to a String to a Form that shows a Dialog for user input and then pass the input String back out.  I have followed several other questions on this and just can not get the syntax to work.

The form/dialog that I call looks like:

```
public ref class SingleStringUI : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
public:  System::String^ tUserInput;

public:
    SingleStringUI(void)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    SingleStringUI(System::String ^% UserInput)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        tUserInput = UserInput;
    }

private: System::Void SingleStringOKButton_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
         tUserInput = gcnew ystem::String(this->SingleStringTextBox->Text);
}
```

The caller looks like:

```
        SV8::SingleStringUI^ TestMatch;
        System::String^ UserInput;

        TestMatch = (gcnew SV8::SingleStringUI(UserInput));
```

However, when I run this, the string entered into the TextBox is not returned to the caller.  Other examples I have seen indicate that the problem is when I store a local copy in tUserInput.  Any help on getting a copy of the String out of the TextBox appreciated.

Comment: You are trying to access the string before the user had a chance to type it in.  This will of course not work.  Use the form's ShowDialog() method, read the string after it returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-assigning `tUserInput` in `SingleStringOKButton_Click` does not change `UserInput` because `tUserInput` is just a handle to `UserInput` and not a tracking reference to the handle. The only opportunity to change `UserInput` was in the `SingleStringUI` constructor. You could provide an accessor to get the string from the TextBox instead.